# Any way to rebind the left menu button in Elite: Dangerous on the Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, elite-dangerous

On the default and classic control schemes on the Xbox One port of Elite: Dangerous the left hand menu (back button) is bound to the OS friends snap-in.

This is useless most of the time, as friends list is already readily available through the snap in menu. It's also a little frustrating as in most games this button is bound to an in-game menu (inventory, skill-tree, crafting, etc) so it snapping out of the game is rather unexpected.

Is there any way to bind it to something that makes sense like the system map, galaxy map or Galcon powers/news?

Answer (score 1):

**No...** unless you want to invest some time and currency.

Two straight-forward ways to re-bind the controls do not work. The game itself won't allow you to bind that specific button and the [Xbox Accessories App](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/customize-standard-controller-with-accessories-app), which allows you to rebind controller buttons, does not allow to rebind that specific button.

What you are left with are third party tools like, for example, the [Titan One](http://www.consoletuner.com/products/titan-one/). Devices like these are able to remap controller input to one or more inputs. Hence, you could rebind the specific button you are asking about to, say, Y (held) and left to get the Galaxy Map.

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly interesting, as I have started playing E:D on PC, with an Xbox One Elite controller (wireless). Here in this default config, [Back] is bound to `Toggle Hardpoints`.